# How to get the correct path for a django script

Tags: python-3.x, django

Here is my arborescence

V1 :

```
project/
---AppUser/
------models.py, view.Py etc ...
---project/
------settings.py, manage.py etc ...
myscript.py
```

here my script works perfectly :

```
import sys
import os
import django


sys.path.append("../../../project")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"
django.setup()


from AppUser.models import Subscription


maps = Subscription.objects.get(uuid="1234565")

print(maps)
```

It works fine, i launch it from the root of the project ...

But when i want to put my script in a script folder :

V2 :

```
project/
---AppUser/
------models.py, view.py etc ...
---project/
------settings.py, manage.py etc ...
---script/
------myscript.py
```

Here is my script :

```
import sys
import os
import django


sys.path.append("../../../../project")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"
django.setup()


from AppUser.models import Subscription


maps = Subscription.objects.get(uuid="123")

print(maps)
```

and when i am in script/
and i do a python3 script.Py

I have a :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 12, in <module>
    from AppUser.models import Subscription
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppUser'
```

error

How to be in script and not having this error ?

The django.setup() seems to works fine, but after it seems to have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To run the script, you don't have to be in the script folder as you already updated the path in the script.

```
sys.path.append("../../../../project")
```

If you want to run from the script folder you can update the path in the script

```
sys.path.append("../../../project")
```

Comment: i have a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project' if a remove one of the ../ in the sys.path.append line thanks for your help btw